# I want to Automatized entry on HTML page

Tags: robotframework

I have two problems, I want to automatized a login and password entry on an HTML page
I wrote this code on RFW :

```
*** Variable ***
${USER}
${PSW}

*** Test Case ***
ENTER_ID    ${USER}    ${PSW}
Input Text       //input[@name="j_name"]    ${USER}
Input Text       //input[@name="j_password"]      ${PSW}


*** Keywords ***
ENTER_ID
[arguments]    ${myUSer}    ${myPSW}

${myUSER}=    Get Value From User    Please enter Name
${myPSW}=    Get Value From User    Please enter password
```

But on the HTML page, nothing is wrote by Robot. Log :

```
INFO : Typing text '' into text field '//input[@name="j_name"]'.
INFO : Typing text '' into text field '//input[@name="j_password"]'.
```

And also the log send me that

```
INFO : ${myUSER} = Paul
INFO : ${myPSW} = MyPassword
```

Variables used are myUSer and myPSW, it should be USER and PSW and I dont understand why

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
*** Variable ***
${USER}
${PSW}
```

means that two variables are creates, variable with name `USER` and variable with name `PSW`. But they are empty.

This:

```
*** Test Case ***
ENTER_ID    ${USER}    ${PSW}
Input Text       //input[@name="j_name"]    ${USER}
Input Text       //input[@name="j_password"]      ${PSW}
```

seems like incorrectly formatted test case. But even if you gave it a name and formatted it properly, you still aren't assigning to those variables `USER` and `PSW` by the time `Input Text` keywords are executed. That's because you're using them as arguments and in keyword:

```
ENTER_ID
    [arguments]    ${myUSer}    ${myPSW}
    ${myUSER}=    Get Value From User    Please enter Name
    ${myPSW}=    Get Value From User    Please enter password
```

there's no assignment into these two variables you're later using with `Input Text` keywords.

---

A working code would be:

```
*** Variables ***
${USER}
${PWD}

*** Test Cases ***
Input User And Pwd
    Ask For Credentials
    Input Text       //input[@name="j_name"]    ${USER}
    Input Text       //input[@name="j_password"]      ${PWD}

*** Keywords ***
Ask For Credentials
    ${user}=    Get Value From User    Please enter Name
    ${pwd}=    Get Value From User    Please enter password
    Set Suite Variable    ${USER}    ${user}
    Set Suite Variable    ${PWD}    ${pwd}
```

`Set Suite Variable` or `Set Global Variable` is necessary here, because simple `Set Variable` will create only local variables, but you want to assign to `USER` and `PWD` in a keyword but use them in a test case elsewhere.

Personally, I'd rather go for an option with a return value, that seems a bit more secure than working with suite or global variables:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Input User And Pwd
    ${credentials}=    Ask For Credentials
    Input Text       //input[@name="j_name"]    ${credentials.user}
    Input Text       //input[@name="j_password"]      ${credentials.pwd}

*** Keywords ***
Ask For Credentials
    ${user}=    Get Value From User    Please enter Name
    ${pwd}=    Get Value From User    Please enter password
    ${credentials} =    Create Dictionary    user=${user}    pwd=${pwd}
    [Return]    ${credentials}
```

By this time, you realise, you don't really need those `USER` and `PWD` variables at all (unless you wan't to use them for something more like setting default values).

Comment: It works ! Thank youI understand why now
I needs USER and PSW after for default value yes ;)

Comment: Do you now if it exist a way to ask sveral values at the same time, the actual code ask for USER and PSW in two separate popUP, is it possible to aski it in only one popUP ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know how to do it. Dialogs library doesn't support it.

Comment: arf does the best thing it to do it myself then ? (By writing a python library)